# This code is of chess game. What is represented by 'DISTANCE' in code?

Tags: chess

```
package chess;

public class Evaluate {   
public static final int PIECE_KING = 0;   
public static final int PIECE_QUEEN = 1;   
public static final int PIECE_ROOK = 2;
public static final int PIECE_BISHOP = 3;
public static final int PIECE_KNIGHT = 4;
public static final int PIECE_PAWN = 5;
public static final int FULL_BIT_RANK = 4080;
public static final int LAZY_MARGIN = 100;
public static final int ISOLATED_PENALTY = 10;
public static final int DOUBLE_PENALTY = 4;
public static final int[] PIECE_VALUE = { 0, 9, 5, 3, 3, 1 };

  public static final int[] PASS_PAWN = { 0, 35, 30, 20, 10, 5 };

  public static final byte[] DISTANCE = { 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 7, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
    0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
    0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 7, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7 };
```

Comment: Not nearly enough information provided to make this answerable in my opinion. And even if you did, it's such a specific question, I sincerely doubt it would be useful to anyone else.

Comment: Without any more information, Some variables and nothing more mean nothing to us. Is this the code you are using? http://j2me-chess.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2010/1/src/chess/

Comment: I even doubt it would be useful to yourself!

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing it is the Manhattan distance to the center in a program that uses an 0x88 board representation (that's why it's 16x16).

Comment: It's actually 241 cells. But according to to the [original source code](http://www.koders.com/java/fid2A9848F82F5F12FA4F0D7454B233256495BD652D.aspx?s=ResponseSideEffect) it is indeed a lookup table for the Manhattan distance between two squares on a 0x88 board.